Packaging cross-platform Appimages and DEB Packages in Linux missing dependencies
I have a JavaFX Application, and I'm using maven to distribute it. Currently, I first create a runtime image of my program with jlink, and then package it with jpackage.
However, if I package either a AppImage or a DEB it in a more updated linux distro (e.g. Arch or Debian Unstable/Trixie), and then try to run it in a stable distro (e.g Debian <13), it doesn't run it, because of missing dependencies.
Here is a summarized version of my pom.xml, and what I'm currently doing to package my program:
xml
<plugins>
    <!-- Plugin to create modularized image -->
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.8</version>
        <configuration>
            <compress>2</compress>
            <noHeaderFiles>false</noHeaderFiles>
            <stripDebug>false</stripDebug>
            <noManPages>true</noManPages>
            <mainClass>com.jurai.Launcher</mainClass>
            <launcher>JurAI</launcher>
            <jlinkImageName>JurAI</jlinkImageName>
            <jlinkZipName>JurAI</jlinkZipName>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>

    <!-- JPackage -->
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.panteleyev</groupId>
        <artifactId>jpackage-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.5</version>

        <configuration>
            <name>JurAI</name>
            <appVersion>0.0.1</appVersion>
            <vendor>com.jurai</vendor>
            <destination>target/dist</destination>
            <module>jurai/com.jurai.Launcher</module>
            <runtimeImage>target/JurAI</runtimeImage>
            <icon>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/img/icon.png</icon>
            <javaOptions>
            <option>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</option>
            </javaOptions>
        </configuration>

        <!-- OS specific configurations -->
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>linux_appimage</id>
                <configuration>
                    <type>APP_IMAGE</type>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>linux_deb</id>
                <configuration>
                    <type>DEB</type>
                    <linuxShortcut>true</linuxShortcut>
                    <linuxPackageName>jurai</linuxPackageName>
                    <linuxAppCategory>Utilities</linuxAppCategory>
                    <linuxMenuGroup>Utilities</linuxMenuGroup>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>

To build a .deb package, I run mvn clean compile javafx:jlink jpackage:jpackage@linux_deb, which creates a standard deb packae.
To create a .AppImage package, I run mvn clean compile javafx:jlink jpackage:jpackage@linux_appimage. This creates a bare bones binary with libs of my project, which I then have to format into a .AppDir directory, according to the AppDir Appimage specification. Finally, I create the AppImage with AppImageTool.
To build the AppImage, I use a Arch Linux system with OpenJDK 22 installed, and to build the DEB, I use a Debian Trixie (unstable) system with OpenJDK 22 installed. Using stable versions of Debian doesn't work, as they don't have the OpenJDK 22 package.
Both files work just fine in updated OS's, but once you try to run them in a older OS, the AppImage just doesn't run at all, and the DEB package reports dependency problems with libglib, libasound and libpng.
From my understanding of Jlink and AppImages, they should include all necessary libs to run the program, but that doesn't seem to be the case here. Is there something I'm missing? Any insight is deeply appreciated.

What missing dependencies?

@ThorbjørnRavnAndersen As I've said in the post, when trying to install the deb package, it lists libglib, libasound and libpng. Regarding the appimage, running ldd on its extracted binary didn't return any unmet dependencies, and running it with strace and grepping for files not found also didn't give me any dependencies. Running it regularly doesn't print a single line in the terminal.

I missed it in my initial read through. You may want to tighten your focus.

Jpackage packaged jars have their own JDKs included, so they don't require to have a special JDKs installed. Not like a fat jar. What java versions are running on which operation systems? What is the Java version you compiled your project with?

@DavidWeber The operating systems I used to compile were both running OpenJDK 22, while the older operating systems either had no JDK or an older one (17 at most). Still, I would expect the images to work in any OS regardless of JRE, as the JDK was included in the image with jlink and packaged onto binaries with jpackage.
I will maybe try to run the images in an updated OS, such as Arch, but without any JRE, to see if the issue is with the JRE not being included in the JAR or the actual OS missing crucial dependencies.

Could you post your complete pom.xml please? Which Jdk is used when executing jpackage, and which Java version is set in your pom.xml for your project? Jdks are not backwards compatible sometimes.

You could try to use jpackage of jdk 17 and compile your project with jdk 17 too (in pom.xml Java version 17 too).
